# understanding a Jquery snippet about Map()

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am very new to JS and Jquery and i have a small difficulty understanding a certain function , I.E. i want to understand the order of execution of a very simple function that i found in the jquery documentation , look below (the example can also be found [here.](http://api.jquery.com/map/))::

HTML ::

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <label for="two">2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="two" name="number[]">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="four">4</label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="four" name="number[]">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="six">6</label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="6" id="six" name="number[]">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="eight">8</label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="8" id="eight" name="number[]">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS ::

```
$( ":checkbox" )
  .map(function() {
    return this.id;
  })
  .get()
  .join();
```

The result is ::

```
 "two,four,six,eight".
```

i understand what the indivisual functions are doing above , but can somebody tell me whats the order of execution of the above script .I.E.

is `map()` returning indivisual `id's` to `get()` ? or is it looping over all the `checkbox's` and then passing all the `id's` at once ?

Comment: map operates on the collection set and returns an array of the results you return in the map.

Comment: In this case, it returns an array of strings (id)

Comment: @Taplar , i get what the whole function is doing , my question is , is map() returning indivisual id's to get() ? or is it looping over all the checkbox's and then passing all the id's at once ? , Thanks for your help though !

Comment: As said above, it returns an array.  It operates over the entire set, keeping an internal array of the results, and at the end it returns the result array.

Comment: map() is returning array like object , then you call on it the get() method to get an array on which you can use array protype methods as join()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions are executed in turn, once they complete they hand the result onto the next function, etc.

It's the equivalent of:

```
var first = $( ":checkbox" ).map(function() {
    return this.id;
  });
var second = first.get();
var third = second.join();
```

the above is just a shorthand that doesn't require the extra varibales.

Comment: thanks just to reconfirm , only after .map() iterates over all the checkbox's does get() execute(i mean in my version of the code) ?

Answer (score 2):

***is map() returning indivisual id's to get() ? or is it looping over all the checkbox's and then passing all the id's at once***

As per docs for `.map()`,

> Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values

**Answer:** It loops over all the elements available in object and append the id in array at a time. The array generated from `.map()` is jquery object. `.get()` converts the object into value array.

Comment: But OP  is using jQuery. fn.map

Answer (score 0):

the order is as you read it , I mean

1-

```
   $( ":checkbox" )
  .map(function() {
    return this.id;
  })
```

2- `get()`

3- `join()`

Comment: Nooooooo :D not that order my question is s map() returning indivisual id's to get() ? or is it looping over all the checkbox's and then passing all the id's at once ?

Comment: First query is processed totally, this means loop all checkbox. 
Then secong query is processed with result of checkbox.
Then third